# how to implement firebase notification from both client and server side of android app?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I was quite friendly with GCM notification but didn't understand firebase notifications please help me with any working example of firebase notification on both android app and server side/

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-tutorial-using-firebase/ follow this link.

Comment: thanx priyank prajapati